# hecache is always returning the same result

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache, cache-control

I'm developing a web service system. I'm using Spring framework and hecache.
the problem is that when i do my first request to the URL I get the correct result but when I do a second request with another parameter it still returning the same result as the first request. When the cache expires it returns the correct result the first time.

This is my Spring Service method

```
@Cacheable(value="getUserInformation", key="#progid")
public Object getUserInformation(String login, String progid, HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println( login.concat(progid) );
    try {
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall   = new   SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).
                                                withCatalogName("siv_pck_general_functions").
                                                withFunctionName("fn_get_user_information");
        SqlParameterSource out          = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_loginname", login).addValue("p_programid", progid);
        map.put("Result", simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(List.class, out) );
        logger.info( LogUtils.getTypeMessage(request.getRemoteAddr(), request.getRequestURI(), LogUtils.INFO ));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        map.put("Result","Error");
    }
    return map;
}
```

This is my ecache configuration

```
<cache name="getUserInformation" 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" 
    eternal="false" 
    diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
    timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
    transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>
```

This is my Web Service mapping

```
@RequestMapping( value="/getUserInformation/{loginName}/{programId}/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8" )
public Object getUserInformation( @PathVariable String loginName, @PathVariable String programId, @PathVariable String token,HttpServletRequest request){
    httpServletRequest = request;
    String result = validateToken(token);
    if ( "OK".equals(result) ){     
        map.put("Result", service.getUserInformation(loginName, programId, request) );
    }else{
        map.put("Result",result);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: What I see here looks correct - what's the result of testing this code only vs. a full webservice call?

Comment: The problem is that login variable is a primary key in my database. And the function returns the correct information but when I call the cacheable function with a login value it returns the corresponding information to the login id if I call that function one more time with another login id it returns the information that the first call returned.

Comment: I understood that from the initial problem description. But you mention a webservice call while the code shown only carries a caching annotation. So I assumed you have more code doing the WS binding and exposition. Maybe the problem is in that code. Which led me to ask what happens if you were to test the service presented here in isolation (but still in a Spring context).